# Computing conjugacy between two elements of $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$

Tags: gr.group-theory, linear-algebra, gt.geometric-topology, computer-algebra

The conjugacy classes of $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ are well characterized (see, e.g., [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/236151/conjugacy-classes-of-mathrmsl-2-mathbbz)). Assuming two matrices $A, B \in \mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ are conjugate, is there a way to compute their conjugacy, i.e. construct a matrix $C \in \mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ such that $A C = C B$?

Comment: Sure, just enumerate and try all matrices $C \in \operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbf{Z})$, and you’ll eventually find one. Perhaps you mean to ask whether there is a more efficient way than this?

Comment: Isn't there a more efficient way by first finding all rational solutions to $AC=CB$ (4 linear equations in 4 unknowns, solution space of dimension 2)?

Comment: Thanks @PaulLevy. With all solutions having the form $a C_1 + b C_2$ (with some rational matrices $C_1, C_2$), the problem then boils down to solving $1 = \det (a C_1 + b C_2) = a^2 \det C_1 + b^2 \det C_2 + a b \det C_1 \operatorname{tr} (C_1^{-1} C_2)$ ?

Comment: For efficiency, it might depend a bit on the input: is it a pair of group words in terms of generators, of a pair of matrices? In the second case the best algorithm might anyway require writing the element as such a group word.

Comment: In any case the approach writing as a word and solving the conjugacy problem in $(P)SL_2(Z)$ yields a reasonably efficient algorithm. (I'm writing $PSL_2$ since it's simpler, being a free product $C_2*C_3$, and two matrices of nonzero same trace are conjugate in $SL_2$ iff their images in $PSL_2$ are conjugate.)

Comment: For $A \in \ SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ let $Q(A)$ as the quadratic form on $\mathbb{Z^2}$ that maps  $x$ to $\det(x, A(x))$.  Reduction algorithms for quadratic forms on $\mathbb{Z^2}$ are well known in the literature. So I think that reducing $Q(A)$ and $Q(B)$  for $A, B  \in SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ to a common quadratic form will solve the problem in most cases.

If $Q(A)$ and $Q(B)$ are indefinite equivalent quadratic forms then any matrix in $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ transforming $Q(A)$ to $Q(B)$ may have rather large entries.

Comment: As I said in my comment to the answer below, if you are looking for software to do this, then Magma has a built in function for testing two elements of ${\rm GL}(n,{\mathbb Z})$ for conjugacy (there is a paper on the method by Eick, Hoffman and O'Brien),

Comment: This problem has essentially been solved by Gauss in his Disquisitiones arithmeticae (1801), as it involves finding transformations between equivalent integral binary quadratic forms.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to a soft as Maple , Mathematica or Sage, you can proceed as follows. Let $A,B\in \mathrm{SL}_2$ be conjugate.

Step 1. Using a Grobner basis library, you solve the equation in $X=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}$ $XB-AX=0,\det(X)=1$ ($5$ equations in the $4$ unknowns $(a_{i,j}))$.
Since the dimension of the algebraic set of the solutions is $1$, you group the unknowns into 2 blocks, for example $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$. In this way , you obtain $3$ equations, the first $2$ of degree $1$ and the last one, denoted by (*), is a quadratic function of $(c,d)$ ($uc^2+vd^2+wcd+t=0$). The calculation must be instantaneous with $70$ digits; otherwise change the couples of unknowns.

Step 2. You solve (*); you can do that on line here

https://www.alpertron.com.ar/QUAD.HTM

This type of equations admits an infinity of solutions except for example if we consider the equation $x^2+y^2+1=0$ which, I think so, does not have many solutions.
We obtain one or several primitive solutions and also one or several recursive solutions starting with primitive solutions. With $70$ digits, the time of calculation is $20"$.

Step 3.  The problem is that the first $2$ equations have the form: $pa+qb=r(c,d),p_1a+q_1b=r_1(c,d)$; then the solution obtained in the last equation must kill the denominator $pq_1-p_1q$.

Fortunately, in all the tests I carried out, a primitive solution was suitable. I don't know if this is general or at least generic; however, if not, then we have to use the recurrence formulas.

That follows is an example:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The matrices in your example  appear to be images, and I could not cut and paste them. If we are discussing available software, then Magma has a fast built in function for testing elements of ${\rm GL}(n,{\mathbb Z})$ for conjugacy, and I expect GAP has something similar.

Comment: @DerekHolt ,  indeed, Magma spoils the work.